# WQL Query on SCCM Server Bitlocker - Not Updating

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, sccm

On our SCCM server we are running the query below to detect computers with Bitlocker not enabled. Since running this we have set bitlocker on some of the computers which from the result set, but this seems to fail when refreshing the query in SCCM. Can anyone advise on what is happening and what is required for the client to update it's status?

```
select SMS_R_System.Name,SMS_R_System.LastLogonUserName,SMS_G_System_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME.ProtectionStatus   from  SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME on SMS_G_System_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId inner join SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM on SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME.ProtectionStatus = 0 and SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.Version > "10.0.14393"
```

Comment: The most probable source of this information is hardware inventory which by default only happens every 7 days. Could this be the case or did you change that time?

Comment: Thanks, we have changed the schedule of the hardware inventory cycle and also tried running it manually, but it still doesn't seem to update the status on SCCM.

Comment: Hi, this is still not updating after a couple of weeks, can anyone advise?

Comment: Didn't want to further comment on this since it seemed I was wrong but as there are no other ideas I checked again. So in the client settings where you can chose your classes for ahrdware inventory there is definitely win32_encryptablevolume for bitlocker infos which contains proctection status. I therefore really doubt it is any other inventory. However this is not on by default. could you check whether it is active for you or whether it maybe is only active for some clients? (client settings can differ on a collection base)

Comment: Hi, these are set up on the default client settings, I can see that all of the below are checked.

BitLocker (Win32_EncryptableVolume)
 Device ID
 Drive Letter
 Persistent Volume ID
 Protection Status

Comment: and if you check on an example client Win32_EncryptableVolume does have a different value for ProtectionStatus than the site site server lists? Or does this already not reflect the Bitlocker status?

Comment: Thanks, I believe I have now found what it is. Where users have an external drive connected, it is not picking up the status for the C drive. I added the clause SMS_G_System_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME.DriveLetter = "C:" to the query and it should now only be looking at the C drive on computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to add the clause SMS_G_System_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME.DriveLetter = "C:" to the query so that it was only checking the C drive status.